# Connect to RabbitMQ in docker-container from another container

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I'am trying to connect web- application, deployed from one container, to rabbitmq, deployed at another container.

By relying on this  [Connecting to RabbitMQ container with docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031439/connecting-to-rabbitmq-container-with-docker-compose)  , I created the following docker-compose:

```
 version: '3'

  services:
     webapp:
        container_name: chat
        build:
        context: .
        depends_on:
          - broker
        links:
          - broker
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"

 broker:
    container_name: rabbit_chat
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    healthcheck:
       test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://broker:15672"]
       interval: 30s
       timeout: 10s
       retries: 5
```

webapp is a service of web-application, at which I prescribe following rabbitmq-properties:

```
  host = broker
  port = 15672
  login = guest
  password = guest
```

I changed 'broker' as a host, as in documentation recommended to connect containers by default-net, using the name of service in docker-compose. Also I tried to use "localhost" as host for connection.

And this does not work.

Additionally, Inspecting container "rabbit_chat" I see in output:

```
 "Log": [
                {
                    "Start": "2020-04-11T14:54:25.0988242Z",
                    "End": "2020-04-11T14:54:25.2920557Z",
                    "ExitCode": -1,
                    "Output": "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"curl\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\": unknown"
                }
```

Also I tried to connect them by bridge-network. In this case I used IP of broker-container as host for requests. And it does not work to. When I connect my app with rabbitMQ on host (without containers) it works properly... So, I confused...

docker ps result:

```
   a53833fb96c2        chat_webapp         "catalina.sh run"        About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp                          chat
   696cbafbd38b        rabbitmq            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    4369/tcp, 5671-5672/tcp, 15672/tcp, 25672/tcp   rabbit_chat
```

Inside rabbit_chat-container I send request (webapp:8080) successfully. But when I send "curl broker:5672 --output - " inside chat-container, I received: "curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer"

Inside rabbit_chat-container I run "ncat -v --listen 5672". And receive "Ncat: bind to :::5672: Address already in use. QUITTING.

Comment: port `15672` is for admin panel. Use port `5672`.

Comment: the error reflects for missing curl binary on the machine. this shouldn't solve the problem mentioned here

Comment: Are both containers on the same network?

Comment: Marius, I suppose  docker-compose up  generate default network automatically

Comment: If you delete the `container_name:`, `links:`, and `healthcheck:` sections, the Compose file should still have the same effect but be shorter.  (`docker-compose up` [doesn't wait for the dependency to be ready](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/).)  What happens if you try this?

Comment: David, I deleted this sections. But nothing is changed. I still cant connect apps

Comment: d0niek,  following you advice, I changed in app request on.   broker:5672.    But without result...

Comment: show us `docker ps`

Comment: Frank, I did it

Comment: Can you access anything on the rabbitmq/broker container from the host machine, like the management console on port 15672 ? I think it is only listening on localhost/127.0.0.1.

Comment: No, I cant listen  localhost:15672

Comment: And Inside rabbit_chat-container I run "ncat -v --listen 5672". And receive "Ncat: bind to :::5672: Address already in use. QUITTING.

Comment: What OS are you host running (win/mac/linux)? try do a `netstat -ln --tcp` show us the output

Comment: I use Mac OS  at host-machine. And I cant run in Mac   "netstat -ln --tcp"

Comment: @Andrew Open an Terminal and write `netstat -an -ptcp | grep LISTEN`.

Comment: I did it. As a result: 5672 and 15671 are LISTEN